# How to let the ScrollPanel (containing many widgets) to scroll to a specific widget in it, in GWT?

Tags: gwt, scroll, scrollbar

Ok, I have a scrollpanel that holds 1 HTMLPanel which has many FlowPanel in it. Ex:

```
 <ScrollPanel>
   <HTMLPanel>
     <FlowPanel1> 
     <FlowPanel2>
     <FlowPanel3> ......
   </HTMLPanel>
 </ScrollPanel>
```

Each FlowPanel may be big, sometime user can only see 1 FlowPanel inside ScrollPanel at 1 time. Thus, If they want to see other FlowPanel, then they have to scroll down & look at carefully to find that FlowPanel. This is not good.

SO I want to build many buttons such as (gotoFlowPanel_1_But, gotoFlowPanel_2_But, gotoFlowPanel_3_But, ...). And I want that when user click on that button it will make the correct FlowPanel visible to user, it means if the FlowPanel was hidden further at the bottom of ScrollPanel, the ScrollPanel will automatically scroll down to the position of that FlowPanel & show it visibly to user.

This is the code when the gotoFlowPanel_1_But is clicked

```
myScrollPanel.setPosition(flowPanel1.getAbsoluteTop());
```

When i first clicked on the gotoFlowPanel_1_But button, then it jumped to correct FlowPanel1. However, when i clicked that button again, the position was changed & the scrollbar was scrolled down quite a bit. But if i clicked that button again, then it showed correct, but when i clicked it 1 more time it showed wrong position.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the *ensureVisible(UIObject item)* method in the *ScrollPanel* class? See [GWT documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#ensureVisible%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject%29) for more information...